# pyspark SparkContext issue "Another SparkContext is being constructed"

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I installed Spark on my EC2 instance following this tutorial:
https://sparkour.urizone.net/recipes/installing-ec2/#03
but when I try to start pyspark shell, I get this error:
"Another SparkContext is being constructed"

Here is the full exception:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-153 ~]$ pyspark
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep  1 2016, 22:14:00) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/08/22 11:46:16 WARN spark.SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 54, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 273, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I googled a lot and tried everything with no solution. I used this code to get a list of all running Contexts:

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkConf
>>> conf = SparkConf()
>>> conf.getAll()
```

And I got this:

```
[(u'spark.master', u'local[*]'), (u'spark.submit.deployMode', u'client'), (u'spark.app.name', u'PySparkShell')]
```

Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Comment: if you are running pyspark, you don't need to create a new context...

Comment: I'm not. This error I get when I start pyspark. Right after I write the command pyspark

Comment: no idea yet? Anyone?

Comment: The real issue is the "threw an exception in its constructor" and not "Another SparkContext is being constructed". If you look down in the stack trace you will see the error raised in constructor: "An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$". 
While the message is a bit misleading, the problem is an env config (e.g. master URL, etc.). Try to research that. If you're using AWS, why not use EMR?

Comment: I didn't know about EMR before. I'll give it a try. 
By the way I solved the problem by setting the SPARK_MASTER_HOST=127.0.0.1 in spark-env.sh file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the SPARK_MASTER_HOST=127.0.0.1 in spark-env.sh file

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error while trying to run PySpark in Jupyter Notebook (on macOS). The problem seems related to a Java version incompatibility and it only works with Java 8. I fixed the issue by changing the java version:

check java (JVM) installation versions. If you don't have java 8 installed, install it following instructions for your OS.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

change the version to Java 8 (it is enough to do it for the current session)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8....
```

check:

```
java -version
```

run PySpark. that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to  Spark config folder:

```
cd $SPARK_HOME/conf
```

Open spark-env.sh file using an editor (is this file does not exist copy the spark-env-template file):

```
vi spark-env.sh
```

edit the SPARK_LOCAL_IP value to your machine IP (e.g. 205.210.42.205) :

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP="205.210.42.205"
```

Hope this helps.